# Customize Default Value of Input Fields

Tags: modeling, interface, customization

Is it possible to customize the **default value of an input field**, so that 
- for instance - 
when using the Bridge Edge Loop Tool, **I can set the "Cuts"-Parameter default value, which is 0, to my custom one that is supposed to be 1**?

There are quite a few inputs that I need to set up with the same value every time I run them, like B-Surfaces which has 3 in its Follow-Parameter Default which I reset to 0 every single time I run it. **The Ability to save a custom Default for inputs that can be reset to factory default would be very valuable to me.**

[image: Default Parameter with Value of 0]
[image: Default Parameter changed to Custom Value of 1]

Comment: Same question. But I know that this is possible, because in the process of work I pressed something several times, which led to the preservation of the instrument parameters. But what exactly it was, I did not understand, it was a missclick for me.

Comment: Did you maybe save the file as a Startup Document? I thought that might do it, but when I tried it out with a few operators, I could not get it to work.